# $out stage in a mongodb pipeline is taking a lot of time

Tags: mongodb, performance, openstreetmap

I am working on some data in mongodb, I ran an aggregate pipeline that takes few seconds to work :

```
db.aarhus_ways.aggregate([{$lookup:{from: "aarhus_nodes",localField: 
"node_refs",foreignField: "id",as: "nodes"}},{"$project":
{"id":1,"name":1,"highway":1,"nodes.pos":1}}])
```

Now i want to add this output to a collection, that's when things get dead slow:

```
db.aarhus_ways.aggregate([{$lookup:{from: "aarhus_nodes",localField: 
"node_refs",foreignField: "id",as: "nodes"}},{"$project":
{"id":1,"name":1,"highway":1,"nodes.pos":1}}
,{"$out":"nodes"}])
```

It's been now half an hour and the aggregate is still running.
is it normal assuming that the data concerns the city of aarhus in Denmark which in mongodb takes (bytes) :

```
db.aarhus_ways.totalSize()  --> 7991296 = nearly 8 MB
db.aarhus_nodes.totalSize() --> 35987456 = nearly 36 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create index on local and foreignField by just issuing command:

```
db.aarhus_ways.createIndex({node_refs:1})
db.aarhus_nodes.createIndex({id:1})
```

then you execute your command:

```
db.aarhus_ways.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "aarhus_nodes",
        localField: "node_refs",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "nodes"
    }
},{
    "$project": {
        "id":1,
        "name":1,
        "highway":1,
        "nodes.pos":1
    }
},{
    "$out":"nodes"
}])
```